# Printing on new line - python

Tags: python-3.x

having some trouble

```
stu = []
inp = input('Students: ')
stu.append(inp)
print('Class Roll')
for i in stu:
  print(i)
```

All I want this to do is print all of the inputs in 'stu' on a new line each. I've tried the split command with no luck. Currently, they are printed all on the same line. eg. if I typed 'James John Josh,' I want it to output
James
John
Josh

Comment: I see no `split`. What have you tried? `stu.append(inp.split())`? Try `stu.extend(inp.split())` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try this simple example:

```
>>> stu = []
>>> inp = input('Students: ')
Students: a b c
>>> inp
'a b c'
>>> type(inp)
<class 'str'>
```

You can see that `inp` is a string and therefore there's just one record in `stu`.

I'm not sure whether you are expecting just space separated (or other separator) names like `John, Joe, Josh` or so, in which case you should use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> stu += inp.split(' ')
>>> stu
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Or do it in a loop:

```
stu = []
while True:
    inp = input('Add a student: ')
    if not inp:
        break
    stu.append(inp)
```

Also read the difference between [`list.append()` and `list.expand()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). `append` creates **one** new item in the list while `expand` (or `+=` operator) iterates trough iterable object `x` and adds new item in **every iteration**.

But your printing loop is correct:

```
>>> stu = []
>>> inp = input('Students: ')
Students: Joe Josh John
>>> inp.split(' ')
['Joe', 'Josh', 'John']
>>> stu += inp.split(' ')
>>> print('Class Roll')
Class Roll
>>> for i in stu:
...   print(i)
...
Joe
Josh
John
```

Comment: sorry, bad explanation. I don't want any commas, basically if I were to input 'James Josh John Yas,' I want it to output by printing each of those names on a new line

Comment: @user3879060 I've created working example for your and added few notes on append/expand methods.