# How to print out the letters of a word, one on each line, with three asterisks before and after the word

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to Python and trying hard to learn it. Got stuck on this exercise: "Print out the letters of a word, one on each line, with three asterisks before and after the word."

The outcome should look like that:

```
Enter a word: sky 
***
s
k
y
***
```

My code is:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
for i in word:
    print(i)
```

I ran out of the ideas on how to insert asterisks in it.

Comment: `print('***')` before and after the `for` loop?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just too basic...

Comment: No. Should be before and after the word I input. But each letter of this word should be on separate line as well (example : sky)
    ***
    s
    k
    y
   ***
So for word "sky" should be 5 lines all together.

Comment: yup, exactly my proposal; the explicit answer given below...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing on new line - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032904/printing-on-new-line-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
print("***")
for letter in word:
    print(letter)
print("***")
```